# Plotting two scatter plots and regression lines with error bars on same plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create the following diagram:

[image: Depicts two different scatter plots on same plot, with different markers and displays each of their linear fits, LSRL in R.]

So far, I have: 
`ggplot(df, aes(x = IOD, y = movement_time, color = cursor, shape = cursor))` 
but I am not having any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have reproducible data you can post? And what have you tried to do?

Comment: So, you'll need to 1. read data into R (see `?read.table`), 2. get a best fit line (see `?lm`), 3. make a plot (see `?plot`). Give it a go, and then when you have a specific problem, run through the examples at the bottom of the appropriate help file. If you're still stuck, then post a specific question.

Comment: You will also need to look at `?legend` and note the 'pch' argument to plot and legend. See examples in http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` is my favourite R package, so here is how I would solve this:

```
df = data.frame(difficulty = 2 + (runif(200) * 6),
                ID = rep(c("point", "bubble"), each = 100))
df$movement = rep(c(1.2, 1.4), each = 100) * df$difficulty + (runif(200) / 5)

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(df, aes(x = difficulty, y = movement, color = ID, shape = ID)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

[image]

Comment: @user3570653 thanks, but I agree with the other people that your question is quite broad, and does not show that you did research yourself first (not saying you didn't, but the question does not show it).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a minor riff on @PaulHiemstra's answer, showing how to move the legend inside the plot area, add a border, and get rid of the grey background. IMO `ggplot` is definitely the way to go.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = difficulty, y = movement, color = ID, shape = ID)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F)+
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0),
        legend.key=element_rect(color=NA),
        legend.background=element_rect(color="black"))
```

[image]

NB: You get the grey background because `stat_smooth(...)` plots confidence bands by default (which are grey). Setting `se=F` turns that off.